# How to reposition in CSS the block of Tags completely at the top of the homepage at the level of the part circled in red?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming, customization, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to position the block of Keywords "***Beautiful, business, Cities, Macbook, World***" visible on the screenshot just above "***Main Stories, Editor's Pick, Trending Stories***" at **the level of the part framed in red** on the following screenshot: .

That is to say that I would like to move the content of the widget CSS class widget_block widget_tag_cloud **to the part framed in red** on the following screenshot:.

I tried adding a `margin-bottom: 121px;` on the class `widget` in the HTML-CSS code inspector of the browser to see the rendering but it completely shifted the page.

I therefore request your help to help me reposition the Tags whose content of the CSS class is `widget widget_block widget_tag_cloud` and place them at the top, just above the block "**Main Stories, Editor's Pick, Trending Stories**" and more precisely on the part circled in red on the screenshot:.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have checked your issue. And the solution is just you can use the inserBefore on jquery like the below code.

```
jQuery("section#block-14").insertBefore(".gutter-parent-10 > .col-lg-5.col-xl-6");
```

After that, you can add the below style. So I hope you can get exactly what you want

```
section#block-14 {
    width: 100%;
}
```